# how is a value search(find) to database(table) in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery

i want display result search live(online) and search letters to letters (transliteration). how echo(print) result search(of database) with jQuery( to success: function(data) )?

> For example, the I mean apparent:
>  i have to database this words :
>   salam, salavat, sabos, sandal, sefid, siah and ...
>  i type to
>   search box : s --display this words--> salam, salavat, sabos, sandal,
>   sefid, siah
>  now if type :  sa --display this words--> salam,
>   salavat, sabos, sandal,
>  if type :  sala --display this words-->
>   salam, salavat
>  if type :  salam --display this words--> salam

I hope you understand my mean.
what is your comment?

my code:

```
$('#hotel').keypress(function () {
    var dataObj = $(this).closest('form').serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/admin/tour/search_hotel',
        data: dataObj,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            // Display the results
            alert(data);
        },
        "error": function (x, y, z) {
            // callback to run if an error occurs
            alert("An error has occured:\n" + x + "\n" + y + "\n" + z);
        }
    });
});
```

with respect

Comment: cant figure out what you asked but may be jquery ui autocomplete  is waht you are looking for  http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: Yes, something like it. but not want use of jquery ui or anything other i want create myself it. how echo value get of database?

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify url where your script returns correct json object/array

```
$('#hotel').keypress(function () {
    var dataObj = $(this).closest('form').serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/admin/tour/search_hotel/search_script.php',
        data: dataObj,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#suggestion_tab").html('');
            $.each(data.suggestions, function(a,b){
                $("#suggestion_tab").append('<li>'+data.b+'</li>');
            });
            // Display the results
            ///alert(data);
        },
        "error": function (x, y, z) {
            // callback to run if an error occurs
            alert("An error has occured:\n" + x + "\n" + y + "\n" + z);
        }
    });
});
```

//search_script.php:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ....");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $output[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode(array("suggestions" => $output));
```

Comment: this code have error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in
D:\xampp\htdocs\application\controllers\admin\tour.php on
line 25.
line 25 is: echo json_encode('suggestions' => $output);
what do i do?

Comment: my change and I've solved with: echo json_encode(array('suggestions' => $output)); error give me ajax call: An error has occured:
[object Object]
error
Not Found. what is your comment?